# How to write multiple variable using fwrite() in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, text

I have a script that is writing variables to a text file, I am using fwrite(). here is the script:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$filename = 'Report.txt';


$batch_id = $_GET['batch_id'];
$status = $_GET['status'];
$phone_number = $_GET['phone_number'];

//check to see if I could open the report.txt
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    // I am trying to write each variables to the text file
    if (fwrite($handle, $phone_number) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($phone_number) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);


?>
```

I have 2 problems here:

1.As I receive the report by Batch_ID I want to name each report text file with a prefix using the batch_ID for example :5626_Report.txt

2.I want to pass more than one variable to the function fwrite(), I want to write the $status next to each $phone_number.

Comment: There is no shame in not knowing something. There is no shame in asking for help either. However there is shame in not even trying and expecting others to solve your problems for you. I don't think you did that here, hence I see no reason to vote your question down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try fprintf.

It's analogue to the regular printf of C, however you need to pass a handle to.
As an example:

```
fprintf($handle, "%s;%s;%s", $batch_id, $status, $phone_number);
```

Alternatively, you can make use of PHPs inline stringing and use:

```
fwrite($handle "$batch_id;$status;$phone_number");
```

To get to your exact problem:

```
$filename = $batch_id."_report.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "a");
fwrite($handle, "$phone_number $status");
```

That should help.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this solved half my problem however when the file gets created the name is _report , the prefix does not show

Comment: For that, you need to make sure that $batch_id is actually set. Use '$batch_id = (isset($_GET['batch_id']) ? $_GET['batch_id'] : "12345";' This will prepend the report.txt with the default value '12345', if batch_id is not set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a lot simpler:

```
$status = $_GET['status'];
$phone_number = $_GET['phone_number'];

$file = $_GET['batch_id']."_Report.txt";
//place here whatever you need
$content = "Some content".$status."\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```